std::ranges compile time (and run time) RFC 4648 compliant Base16 conversions in C++23 (improved 2)
This increment
This obsoletes a former version, after taking a great review into account:

The encoding now preserves sized_range and random_access_range which is one of the most demanding range requirements. This was achieved by replacing a combination of iota, transform and join by cartesian_product, which seems to be much better at preserving range properties. This did however force the implementation to make use of a range_adaptor_closure, instead of just composing range adaptors.
Decoding is now provided as a constrained algorithm instead of a range adaptor. This is because decoding can fail, and range adaptors are not good at reporting failure.

Point 2 complicates things a lot, because it involves memory allocation. The suggested API in the mentioned review needed refinement, and I finally decided to focus on matching a standard library API as closely as possible, namely the std::ranges::transform API. Failure is handled with the help of std::expected, which effectively adds one layer on top of the std::ranges::transform API. Also worth noting, because std::ranges::transform has support for a projection, so does decoding in this implementation.
The decoding function/data structures that may fail have try_ prefixed to their names.
Also, constrained algorithms usually write to an output iterator, an operation which is not guaranteed to be memory safe. Hence, we need one additional encapsulation layer, to provide memory safety.
Returning a std::expected<std::vector<std::byte>, decode16_error> felt like a reasonable goal for such an encapsulation layer, at least to start with. The review hinted at that too. The implementation includes a try_decode16_to template for that, which is implemented for std::vector. For convenience, there is also a decode16_to<std::vector>, which always returns a std::vector, empty if the decoding failed. It should be noted that because the empty vector also is the decoding result of the empty input, which is valid, that function shall not be used for error handling.
Fairly extensive unit testing is provided.
Because std::extended is involved, this implementation and the unit tests make some use of monadic programming.
General background
The following code is an implementation of, in ambition, RFC 4648 compliant Base16 conversions as range adaptors and constrained algorithms in C++23. It can be used at compile time or at run time.
I'll take any feedback, but I am especially interested in feedback from people who have experience of std::ranges, functional programming and lazy evaluation. I have not checked any performance aspect yet, but I have tried to make the implementation efficient.
I am also interested in any feedback on RFC 4648 compliance.
Source code
This can also be found on godbolt.
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <expected>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

enum class decode16_error : signed char {
    illegal_character,
    missing_character,
};

template <typename I, typename O>
struct decode16_error_result {
    std::ranges::in_out_result<I, O> in_out_result;
    decode16_error error;
};

namespace detail {

inline constexpr std::string_view base16_chars{"0123456789ABCDEF"};

namespace encode16 {

struct encode : std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure<encode> {
    template <std::ranges::viewable_range R>
        requires std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>,
                                     std::byte>
    constexpr auto operator()(R &&r) const {
        using namespace std::views;
        return cartesian_product(std::forward<R>(r), iota(0, 2) | reverse) |
               transform([](std::tuple<std::byte, int> indexed_byte) -> char {
                   const auto [byte, i] = indexed_byte;
                   return detail::base16_chars.at(
                       static_cast<unsigned>((byte >> (4 * i))) & 0xF);
               });
    }
};

}  // namespace encode16

namespace decode16 {

constexpr auto max_size(size_t input_size)
    -> std::expected<size_t, decode16_error> {
    if ((input_size % 2) != 0) {
        return std::unexpected{decode16_error::missing_character};
    }

    return input_size / 2;
}

struct try_decode {
    template <std::input_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S,
              std::weakly_incrementable O, typename Proj = std::identity>
        requires(std::convertible_to<std::indirect_result_t<Proj, I>, char> and
                 std::indirectly_writable<O, std::byte>)
    constexpr auto operator()(I first1, S last1, O result, Proj proj = {}) const
        -> std::expected<std::ranges::in_out_result<I, O>,
                         decode16_error_result<I, O>> {
        using namespace std::views;

        using lookup_t =
            std::array<unsigned char,
                       std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() + 1>;

        static constexpr auto is_valid = 0x10;

        static constexpr auto lookup = [] -> lookup_t {
            lookup_t a{};
            unsigned char i{};
            for (const unsigned char c : detail::base16_chars) {
                a.at(c) = is_valid | i++;
            }
            return a;
        }();

        for (; first1 != last1; (void)++result) {
            static constexpr auto chunk_size = 2;
            unsigned char byte{};
            auto i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < chunk_size and first1 != last1; ++i, ++first1) {
                const auto nibble = lookup.at(
                    static_cast<unsigned char>(std::invoke(proj, *first1)));
                if (not(nibble & is_valid)) {
                    return std::unexpected{decode16_error_result<I, O>{
                        .in_out_result = {std::move(first1), std::move(result)},
                        .error = decode16_error::illegal_character,
                    }};
                }
                byte = (byte << 4) | (nibble & 0xF);
            }
            if (i != chunk_size) {
                return std::unexpected{decode16_error_result<I, O>{
                    .in_out_result = {std::move(first1), std::move(result)},
                    .error = decode16_error::missing_character,
                }};
            }
            *result = static_cast<std::byte>(byte);
        }

        return std::ranges::in_out_result<I, O>{std::move(first1),
                                                std::move(result)};
    }

    template <std::ranges::input_range R, std::weakly_incrementable O,
              typename Proj = std::identity>
        requires(std::convertible_to<
                     std::indirect_result_t<Proj, std::ranges::iterator_t<R>>,
                     char> and
                 std::indirectly_writable<O, std::byte>)
    constexpr auto operator()(R &&r, O result, Proj proj = {}) const
        -> std::expected<
            std::ranges::in_out_result<std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R>, O>,
            decode16_error_result<std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R>, O>> {
        return (*this)(std::ranges::begin(r), std::ranges::end(r),
                       std::move(result), std::move(proj));
    }
};

}  // namespace decode16
}  // namespace detail

inline constexpr detail::encode16::encode encode16{};
inline constexpr detail::decode16::try_decode try_decode16{};

template <typename R>
    requires(std::ranges::sized_range<R> or std::ranges::forward_range<R>)
constexpr auto decode16_max_size(R &&r)
    -> std::expected<size_t, decode16_error> {
    if constexpr (std::ranges::sized_range<R>) {
        return detail::decode16::max_size(std::ranges::size(r));
    } else {
        return detail::decode16::max_size(std::ranges::distance(r));
    }
}

namespace detail::decode16 {

template <template <typename> typename C>
struct try_decode_to {
    template <std::ranges::input_range R, typename Proj = std::identity>
        requires std::convertible_to<
            std::indirect_result_t<Proj, std::ranges::iterator_t<R>>, char>
    constexpr auto operator()(R &&r, Proj proj = {}) const
        -> std::expected<C<std::byte>, decode16_error>;
};

template <>
struct try_decode_to<std::vector> {
    template <std::ranges::input_range R, typename Proj = std::identity>
        requires std::convertible_to<
            std::indirect_result_t<Proj, std::ranges::iterator_t<R>>, char>
    constexpr auto operator()(R &&r, Proj proj = {}) const
        -> std::expected<std::vector<std::byte>, decode16_error> {
        std::vector<std::byte> v{};

        return try_decode16(std::forward<R>(r), std::back_insert_iterator{v},
                            std::move(proj))
            .transform(
                [v = std::move(v)](auto &&) mutable { return std::move(v); })
            .transform_error([](const auto &error) { return error.error; });
    }

    template <std::ranges::input_range R, typename Proj = std::identity>
        requires(std::convertible_to<
                     std::indirect_result_t<Proj, std::ranges::iterator_t<R>>,
                     char> and
                 (std::ranges::sized_range<R> or std::ranges::forward_range<R>))
    constexpr auto operator()(R &&r, Proj proj = {}) const
        -> std::expected<std::vector<std::byte>, decode16_error> {
        const auto size = decode16_max_size(std::forward<R>(r));

        if (not size.has_value()) {
            return std::unexpected{size.error()};
        }

        std::vector<std::byte> v(*size);

        return try_decode16(std::forward<R>(r), v.begin(), std::move(proj))
            .transform(
                [v = std::move(v)](auto &&) mutable { return std::move(v); })
            .transform_error([](const auto &error) { return error.error; });
    }
};

template <template <typename> typename C>
    requires std::default_initializable<C<std::byte>>
struct decode_to {
    template <std::ranges::input_range R, typename Proj = std::identity>
        requires std::convertible_to<
            std::indirect_result_t<Proj, std::ranges::iterator_t<R>>, char>
    constexpr auto operator()(R &&r, Proj proj = {}) const -> C<std::byte> {
        return try_decode_to<C>{}(std::forward<R>(r), std::move(proj))
            .value_or(C<std::byte>{});
    }
};

}  // namespace detail::decode16

template <template <typename> typename C>
inline constexpr detail::decode16::try_decode_to<C> try_decode16_to{};

template <template <typename> typename C>
inline constexpr detail::decode16::decode_to<C> decode16_to{};

inline constexpr auto try_decode16_to_vector = try_decode16_to<std::vector>;
inline constexpr auto decode16_to_vector = decode16_to<std::vector>;

// Unit testing

namespace {

constexpr auto to_bytes = std::views::transform(
    [](auto num) -> std::byte { return static_cast<std::byte>(num); });

constexpr auto encoding_is_successful(std::string_view binary,
                                      std::string_view encoded) -> bool {
    /* Check than encoding preserves range features. */
    static_assert(std::ranges::random_access_range<decltype(binary | to_bytes |
                                                            encode16)>);
    static_assert(
        std::ranges::sized_range<decltype(binary | to_bytes | encode16)>);

    return std::ranges::equal(binary | to_bytes | encode16, encoded);
}

template <std::ranges::view V, typename Proj = std::identity>
    requires std::convertible_to<
        std::indirect_result_t<Proj, std::ranges::iterator_t<V>>, char>
constexpr auto decoding_works_as_expected(V encoded, std::string_view binary,
                                          Proj proj = {}) -> bool {
    return try_decode16_to_vector(encoded, std::move(proj))
        .transform([&binary](const auto &v) -> bool {
            return std::ranges::equal(v, binary | to_bytes);
        })
        .value_or(false);
}

template <std::ranges::view V, typename Proj = std::identity>
    requires std::convertible_to<
        std::indirect_result_t<Proj, std::ranges::iterator_t<V>>, char>
constexpr auto decoding_works_as_expected(V encoded,
                                          decode16_error expected_error,
                                          Proj proj = {}) -> bool {
    return try_decode16_to_vector(encoded, std::move(proj))
        .transform_error([expected_error](decode16_error error) -> bool {
            return error == expected_error;
        })
        .error_or(false);
}

template <typename Proj = std::identity>
constexpr auto test_is_successful(std::string_view binary,
                                  std::string_view encoded, Proj proj = {})
    -> bool {
    return encoding_is_successful(binary, encoded) &&
           decoding_works_as_expected(encoded, binary, std::move(proj)) and
           decoding_works_as_expected(binary | to_bytes | encode16, binary,
                                      std::move(proj)) and
           std::ranges::equal(try_decode16_to_vector(encoded).value_or(
                                  std::vector<std::byte>{}) |
                                  encode16,
                              encoded);
}

void test_encoding_non_forward_range(std::string_view binary,
                                     std::string_view encoded) {
    std::istringstream ss{std::string{binary}};
    using view = decltype(std::views::istream<char>(ss));
    static_assert(not std::ranges::forward_range<view>);
    assert(std::ranges::equal(view(ss) | to_bytes | encode16, encoded));
}

void test_decoding_non_forward_range(std::string_view encoded,
                                     auto expected_result) {
    std::istringstream ss{std::string{encoded}};
    using view = decltype(std::views::istream<char>(ss));
    static_assert(not std::ranges::forward_range<view>);
    assert(decoding_works_as_expected(view(ss), expected_result));
}

void test_non_forward_range(std::string_view binary, std::string_view encoded) {
    test_encoding_non_forward_range(binary, encoded);
    test_decoding_non_forward_range(encoded, binary);
}

}  // namespace

auto main() -> int {
    using namespace std::literals;
    using namespace std::views;
    using std::ranges::equal;

    // Test some arbitrary encoding/decoding

    static_assert(
        test_is_successful("\x{01}\x{C0}\x{FF}\x{EE}"sv, "01C0FFEE"sv));

    test_non_forward_range("\x{01}\x{C0}\x{FF}\x{EE}"sv, "01C0FFEE"sv);

    // Test that all the hexadecimal alphabet works

    static_assert(
        test_is_successful("\x{01}\x{23}\x{45}\x{67}\x{89}\x{AB}\x{CD}\x{EF}"sv,
                           "0123456789ABCDEF"sv));

    test_non_forward_range("\x{01}\x{23}\x{45}\x{67}\x{89}\x{AB}\x{CD}\x{EF}"sv,
                           "0123456789ABCDEF"sv);

    // Test decoding rejection in case of illegal characters

    static_assert(decoding_works_as_expected(
        "01C0FZFF\x{00}AEE"sv, decode16_error::illegal_character));
    static_assert(decoding_works_as_expected(
        "01C0FZFF\x{FF}AEE"sv, decode16_error::illegal_character));
    static_assert(decoding_works_as_expected(
        "01C0FF\x{00}AEE"sv, decode16_error::illegal_character));
    static_assert(decoding_works_as_expected(
        "01C0FF\x{FF}AEE"sv, decode16_error::illegal_character));

    test_decoding_non_forward_range("01C0FZFF\x{00}AEE"sv,
                                    decode16_error::illegal_character);
    test_decoding_non_forward_range("01C0FZFF\x{FF}AEE"sv,
                                    decode16_error::illegal_character);
    test_decoding_non_forward_range("01C0FF\x{00}AEE"sv,
                                    decode16_error::illegal_character);
    test_decoding_non_forward_range("01C0FF\x{FF}AEE"sv,
                                    decode16_error::illegal_character);

    // Test decoding an odd number of nibbles

    static_assert(decoding_works_as_expected(
        "01C0FFEE5"sv, decode16_error::missing_character));

    test_decoding_non_forward_range("01C0FFEE5"sv,
                                    decode16_error::missing_character);

    // Test projection

    static_assert(decoding_works_as_expected(
        "01C0FFEE"sv | transform([](char c) { return std::pair{c, char{}}; }),
        "\x{01}\x{C0}\x{FF}\x{EE}"sv, &std::pair<char, char>::first));
    static_assert(decoding_works_as_expected(
        "01C0FFEE5"sv | transform([](char c) { return std::pair{c, char{}}; }),
        decode16_error::missing_character, &std::pair<char, char>::first));

    // Test RFC 4648 test vectors, but in binary, in order to avoid making any
    // assumptions on encoding. Hexadecimal 666F6F626172, in ASCII, is "foobar".

    static_assert(test_is_successful(""sv, ""sv));
    static_assert(test_is_successful("\x{66}"sv, "66"sv));
    static_assert(test_is_successful("\x{66}\x{6F}"sv, "666F"sv));
    static_assert(test_is_successful("\x{66}\x{6F}\x{6F}"sv, "666F6F"sv));
    static_assert(
        test_is_successful("\x{66}\x{6F}\x{6F}\x{62}"sv, "666F6F62"sv));
    static_assert(
        test_is_successful("\x{66}\x{6F}\x{6F}\x{62}\x{61}"sv, "666F6F6261"sv));
    static_assert(test_is_successful("\x{66}\x{6F}\x{6F}\x{62}\x{61}\x{72}"sv,
                                     "666F6F626172"sv));

    test_non_forward_range(""sv, ""sv);
    test_non_forward_range("\x{66}"sv, "66"sv);
    test_non_forward_range("\x{66}\x{6F}"sv, "666F"sv);
    test_non_forward_range("\x{66}\x{6F}\x{6F}"sv, "666F6F"sv);
    test_non_forward_range("\x{66}\x{6F}\x{6F}\x{62}"sv, "666F6F62"sv);
    test_non_forward_range("\x{66}\x{6F}\x{6F}\x{62}\x{61}"sv, "666F6F6261"sv);
    test_non_forward_range("\x{66}\x{6F}\x{6F}\x{62}\x{61}\x{72}"sv,
                           "666F6F626172"sv);

    return 0;
}


While working on a similar implementation for Base64, it appears to me that in this implementation, there is a more generic one struggling to get out. While Base16 maps every 1-tuple of octets to a couple of characters, Base64 maps every triplet of octets to a quadruple of characters. In other words, we should be able to parametrize this whole implementation with a couple of encoding/decoding functions that operate at the octet-tuple/character-tuple level. The tuples sizes {1, 2} respectively {3, 4} may or may not need to be algorithm-parameters of their own.

For Base32, the tuple sizes are {5, 8}. Also, we can derive the tuple sizes from the number of bits used by the encoding, i.e. 4 for Base16, 5 for Base32 and 6 for Base64. There is a natural block size, which is the minimum encoded size including padding, which in bits is the LCM of the previously mentioned number of bits and 8: 8 for 4, i.e. 1 octet, 40 for 5 i.e. 5 octets, and 24 for 6 i.e. 3 octets. Padding is used for any block size larger than 1 octet.

See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/294084/base16-32-64-implementation-for-c-ranges for a similar Base16/32/64 implementation. It is more general, but has no support for input only ranges on the encoding-side.
